# drupal_add_js() does not add .js file from libraries folder

Tags: theming

I have a page callback where I want to add a colorbox library by this code:

```
drupal_add_js('sites/all/libraries/colorbox/jquery.colorbox-min.js', 'file');
```

The file exists, path is right. But in html is this file not included. Why it does not work?

Comment: Looks right. Do you have checked the permission on jquery.colorbox-min.js ? Do you have checked you can access to this file in your browser : "mydomain.tld/sites/all/libraries/colorbox/jquery.colorbox-min.js" ? Do you have checked you really go through the page callback function ?

Comment: Yes to all your points.

Comment: Your cache is cleared? Javascript aggregation is disabled? More questions... :-)

Answer (score 1):

That seems apply to your issue :

> This problem occurs because the path to library is often incorrectly
>   set as
>
> ```
> libraries\colorbox\jquery.colorbox-min.js
> ```
>
> The solution should be to correct the path. You need to place the
>   whole Colorbox plugin directory after unpacking it in
>   sites/all/libraries This means the path should look like
>
> ```
> sites/all/libraries/colorbox/colorbox/jquery.colorbox-min.js
> ```

[Source](http://www.zyxware.com/articles/3116/solved-drupal-colorbox-unable-to-load-colorbox-javascript-libraries)

Comment: The file already is in sites/all/libraries/colorbox directory.

Comment: This is the point. The file don't have to be in "sites/all/libraries/colorbox" but in "sites/all/libraries/colorbox/colorbox". There are two colorbox in this last path.

Comment: It does not help. I moved colorbox into colorbox/colorbox directory but no change.